# How can read text file from position

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, file-io

I'm trying to develop an application which can read files. But I don't know how can I change the position of the reader pointer, any help please?

```
for(int i=0; i<tab.length; i++){

    char cbuf[] = new char[tab[i]];

    try {
        InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(fichier); 
        InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);

                    //I need to change the position of the pointer here
        br.read(cbuf, 0, tab[i]);


        tabS[i] = new String(cbuf);
        System.out.println(tabS[i]);

        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to read your file sequentially?

Comment: what does tab[i] return?

Comment: Play with this: ((line = br.readLine()) != null)

Comment: so are {2, 2, 20, 8, 20, 8, 4, 3, 7, 3, 3, 3, 18, 139}, the character read as an integer?

Answer (score 1):

The [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) command lets you take in the next character. Use a loop to take in characters

```
// reads and prints BufferedReader
     int Alength = 10;
     int array[] = new int [Alength];
     int value = 0;
     int index = 0;
     while((value = br.read()) != -1 && index < Alength)
     {
         array[index++] = value;
     }
```

Comment: this skips somme characters, I just need to move the pointer without skipping characters

Comment: @Gentuzos Well don't just copy and paste it. The point was to show you what to use and an example of how they work. SO isn't a "give the code" site. It's a learning tool

Comment: Okay thank you :)) 
@Daniel But I need to move it without skipping characters

Comment: @Gentuzos understood, look at what I've changed. That should read it in (haven't tested it, will do that)

Answer (score 0):

E.g. code -

```
int c = -1;
while((c=br.read())!=-1){
     //do whatever you like with ch
     char ch = (char)c;
     ...
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [skip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#skip%28long%29).

```
br.skip(1000L);
```

Unfortunately there is no `long tell()` method, so I wonder if it fits.